# How to add a curly brace under numbers to separate sections in a number

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

I am in the process of writing a report, and wish to add a feature like the one shown below to differentiate between sections of a number. I am using Microsoft Word 2016, on Windows 10. Is this feature possible to implement within Microsoft Word or would I need to create an image in Illustrator or Photoshop or another program?

This is the feature:
            [image: Number Differentiation Feature]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce this:

[image]

in Microsoft Word 2013. 
The above is a screenshot taken with Word’s Zoom level set at 200%.

It was a tedious, manual effort. 
It’s a table:

[image]

All the text is Calibri; all paragraphs are 0pt before and after. 
The first row is font size 11pt; the third row is 5pt. 
The second row is
`{Enter{Enter{`
with the following formatting:

[image]

and then text direction set to “bottom to top”
in the “Table Tools” & rarr; “Layout” tab, “Alignment” pane:

[image: Text Direction]

Comment: Word 2103? Wow, you're ahead by 87 years! When will average people get that feature? ;-)

Comment: @TobiasKnauss: Dang, you found me out!  I'm really Zaphod Beeblebrox; I'm a time traveler.  P.S.  I am using Windows 42.

Comment: I hope you have your towel with you! And greetings to Marvin! // can you ask the mice to send me a copy of W42? ;-)

Comment: Microsoft Mice ⟷ Mickey Mouse?  There’s a joke in there somewhere.